# Hover effect is not working,even style written for it correct?

Tags: html, css

I am working on simple design but the problem I'm facing is when i'm hovering on number block i.e 1,2 etc my hover effect is not working for it .
    I want to hover on li and make the whole text digit which is light green in color to white,the style written for it is correct. I do not where the heck is the problem ..

html

```
<ul class="results">
    <li>
        <span class="number">1</span>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="listitem">
            <p class="title">Lorem</p>
            <p class="desc">Lorem lfdfdfdfdfdsfdfdfdf</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.results {
    margin:25px 26px;
}

.results li {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#f6f6f6;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    list-style:none;
    _width:100%;
}

.results li .number {
    height:90px;
    line-height:90px;
    width:90px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#a0daca;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-45px;
    display:block;
}

.results li a {
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:26px 101px 26px 89px;
    position:relative;
}

.results li a .desc {
    display:inline;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#999;
}

.results li a .title {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#666;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    font-family:Montserrat-Regular;
    font-weight:400;
}

#footer {
    height:46px;
    line-height:46px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#a0daca;
    padding:20px 0;
}

#footer a {
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}

.results li:hover .number {
    color:#fff;
}

.results li:hover .listitem {
    background:url(<tag:image_path/>/800017317/arrowhover.png) scroll 98% center no-repeat #a0daca;
}

.results li:hover .title,.results li:hover .desc {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Please me help to get it done. Here is the [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kaulrishab/222cf6yv/)

Comment: Always post relevant code in the question.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal fiddle is there ..can u pls check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the .numbers block inside the  tag
http://jsfiddle.net/222cf6yv/7/

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="listitem"><span class="number">1</span>
```

But I think the core reason is because the line below is not a valid CSS, so whatever CSS you put below it did not get executed:

```
.results li:hover .listitem {
background:url(<tag:image_path/>/800017317/arrowhover.png) scroll 98% center no-repeat #a0daca;
}
```

Comment: ....Thanks Ideally ,u r right but i have a condition i cant put that span inside the a tag

Comment: see my edit above. you need to fix the `.results li:hover .listitem`. `<tag:image_path/>/800017317/arrowhover.png` is not a valid CSS and did not get executed properly. you need a valid path to the image.

Comment: Thanks not valid that actually a framework v r using ...just ignore it..but may its covering the span element

Comment: okay, i got the issue. you need to put the hover green color on `.results li:hover` instead of `.listitem`. I can elaborate more on why if you want, but here is a working fiddle (see line 65). I believe this satisfies all your req

http://jsfiddle.net/222cf6yv/15/

Comment: Bingo!! u did it ...Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6):

Just add `z-index: 1` and `pointer-events: none` to `.results li .number`

```
.results li .number {
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;  /* works in modern browsers */
    /* other styles */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/222cf6yv/8/)**

### or

The simple solution would be to apply the image on hover to the `li` element instead of the `a` element.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/222cf6yv/17/)**

The image which you were adding to the `a` element, on hover, was covering the `span` element.

Comment: @king You didn't mention what to happen on click? if you want to see a hand cursor instead of normal cursor, then use `cursor: pointer`.

Comment: I think his CSS is broken because of `<tag:image_path/>`

Comment: @MelissaHie yeah.. not sure whether OP mentioned that to not show the exact image path or using some kind of scripting language to generate the css. :/

Comment: @Mr_Green Cursor can be shown but click wont work .i want it to working

Answer (score 0):

result layer is overlapped , yes Z-index was the problem.